# One form to insert two models in flask admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm using flask-admin with flask-sqlalchemy as a simple admin interface to create & edit items in our database/flask app.

We have two models one which is a parent and one a child. At the moment our process is:

1. create a new parent item with no children
2. create a new child and set the child's parent

To save time I would like a single form for creating a new parent where we can enter all the details of the parent as well as a child and create the parent then create the child setting a foreign key between the child and the parent that was just created.

Is there a way to do this with flask-admin?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Flask Admin [`inline models`](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/#flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView.inline_models)?

Here is an example with a one-to-many relationship. Unfortunately, FlaskAdmin does not provide complete support for one-to-many relationships ([source](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1405)).

Currently, it only supports providing an inline model on the "one" side of the relationship. Given two models: `Post`, and `Guide`, where `one guide has many posts`, you would have something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///storage.sqlite3'
app.secret_key = 'secret'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# defining the "one" side of the relationship
class Guide(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "guides"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(512), nullable=False)

    posts = db.relationship("Post", back_populates="guide")

# defining the "many" side of the relationship
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    guide_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("guides.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )
    guide = db.relationship("Guide", back_populates="posts")
    

db.create_all()
    
    
admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")

# creating a custom model view for the Guide model.
class ModelViewWithInlineModel(ModelView):
    # here you provide a tuple with the inline models you want to
    # render to the user
    inline_models = (Post,)

# using FlaskAdmin ModelView default implementation for the Post model
admin.add_view(ModelView(Post, db.session))
# using our custom ModelView with the Post as an inline model
admin.add_view(ModelViewWithInlineModel(Guide, db.session))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30442653)

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. Is that good now?